# PHP Cookie Class Configuration

Tags: php, arrays, oop, cookies

I'm writing a cookie class but would like to keep the default configuration in a separate file that just returns an array for reasons specific to the application. I was wondering what the best way would be to get the config array into the class however.  I like the first implementation because it is much cleaner but am wondering if the second implementation is considered a bad practice or not?  I don't want the class to be directly aware or dependent on the outside file but am unsure of the best way of passing it in.

```
/* config/Cookie.php */
return [
    'expire'   => null,
    'path'     => null,
    'domain'   => null,
    'secure'   => false,
    'htpponly' => false
]
```

I was thinking of structuring it in one of two ways:

The first way looks much cleaner to me but I'm not sure how I would get the default config items in.

```
class Cookie
{
    protected $name;
    protected $value;
    protected $expires;
    protected $path;
    protected $domain;
    protected $secure;
    protected $httponly;

    public function __construct($name, $value, $expire = null, $path = null, $doamin = null, $secure = false, $httponly = false)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->value = $value;
        $this->expire = $expire
        // ...
    }
```

Or the second way where a config array is passed into the constructor

```
class Cookie
{
    protected $name;
    protected $value;
    protected $config = array(
        'expire    => null,
        'path'     => null,
        'domain'   => null,
        'secure    => false,
        'httponly' => false
    );

    public function __construct($name, $value, array $config = null)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->value = $value;
        $this->config = array_merge($this->config, $config);
    }

    // ... $name and $value getters

    public function getExpire()
    {
        return $this->config['expire'];
    }
```

Would it be considered bad practice to store class properties in an array?

Comment: Laravel does it. Unless it becomes a cluttered mess, I don't think so.

Comment: This question is primarily opinion based due to the fact that its about the methods in which you think/want it to be implemented. I personally would go for the second option as I prefer a config array/object over numerous variables.

Comment: I agree with @Darren

Comment: Thanks, I'll go with the second option.  I tend to get stuck over-thinking the little things and it helps to get others opinions